# touchpad stops working intermittently, help discovering packeg or kernal issue to troubleshoot or file bug report

Tags: kubuntu, touchpad, debug

So, New thinkpad T14s AMD, Kubuntu 20.10. the touchpad will sometimes stop working.

Sometimes I turn on the laptop and the touchpad works, other times no.

The output of "cat /proc/bus/input/devices" shows Name="SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad". however, also shows, Handlers=mouse0 event6. I don't know if the mouse0 means anything.

running evtest shows no input is registed other than a physical depress (no tap or scroll).

my machine has libinput by default so I installed synaptics, same issues, exactly. So I guess it's not a bug in either of those. But, is it then a kernal issue?

So I am just trying to find a way to troubleshoot/debug and/or find the correct package to file a bug against.

Comment: Have you looked through your logs for things like errors related to input devices? There's a great GUI app called `ksystemlog` that is pretty good for that sort of stuff.

Comment: I am not sure what sort of things to look for when scouring logs for something like this? I have just rebooted and now the touchpad is working again. ksyslog shows kernel seems to load touchpad. the following is from journalctl for both current boot (working) and previous boot (not working) input: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad as /devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input7 seems to load the touchpad. what logs would you suggest I look for?

Comment: I'd look for anything related to the touchpad and input devices. *You may not find anything, but it's worth checking.* Look for errors related to your touchpad. You might find clues in the X.org or Kernel sections as well. Without knowing your exact problem, I can only suggest looking for things that stand out - though they're often helpfully colored red. If you do find anything, tossing the error code into your favorite search engine may yield a fix or at least more information.